# Sending URL Query String through Vue / Axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm pretty new to Vue / Axios.

What I'm trying to do is send the query string through to an email using Axios. The Query string is set from Google Adwords.

http://website.co.uk/page.php?keyword=jh%20page&gclid=XXIaIZobFhEInb6zoDyH3AIViwDTCh1yawIPFYTAYASRAEgIJH_D_BwE

My current vue code

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            step: 1,
            counter: 0,
            tagName: null,
            debt: {
                name: null,
                email: null,
                tel: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        prev() {
            this.step--;
        },
        next() {
            this.step++;
        },
        submit() {
            axios.post('post.php', {
                'name': this.debt.name,
                'email': this.debt.email,
                'tel': this.debt.tel
            }).then(response => {
                console.log('success', response.data.message)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Hopefully, someone can help push me in the right direction. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks, J.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Why not just sending name,email,tel,querystring

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to set a query string with axios it is set in the [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) as params.

```
axios.request('/post.php', {
  method: 'post',
  params: {
    test: '321',
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks, What im looking to do it get the Query String from the URL and then send it to an email using Axios. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: There are a number of ways to parse the query string, one way is to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)